# SQL: Split a column into multiple

Tags: sql, join, h2

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE yow(
  userid INT,
  itemid INT,
  feedback INT,
  value INT)
```

(userid,itemid,feedback) can be considered a primary key, where each of these tuples contains a value.

I want a query which returns a table with the following columns:
userid | itemid | col0 | col1 | col2

Where col0 contains `value` for all rows in `yow` where feedback = 0, and col1 contains `value` where feedback = 1 and so on.

I have a somewhat working query:

```
SELECT
yow.userid AS uid, 
yow.itemid AS iid,
isNull(col0.value, 0) AS col0,
IsNull(col1.value, 0) AS col1,
IsNull(col2.value, 0) AS col2
FROM yow 

LEFT JOIN yow AS col0 ON col0.userid=yow.userid AND col0.itemid=yow.itemid
LEFT JOIN yow AS col1 ON col1.userid=yow.userid AND col1.itemid=yow.itemid
LEFT JOIN yow AS col2 ON col2.userid=yow.userid AND col2.itemid=yow.itemid

WHERE col0.feedback = 0 
AND col1.feedback = 1
AND col2.feedback = 2
GROUP BY uid, iid
```

The problem is that I can have a value for (userid,itemid) in col1 or col2 but not the others. With this query, those rows are filtered out instead of the missing cells defaulting to 0.

As an example, I am getting something like this:

```
+-------+-------+--------+--------+--------+
| UID   | IID   | COL0   | COL1   | COL2   |
+-------+-------+--------+--------+--------+
|     1 |   101 |     23 |     22 |    241 |
|     1 |   101 |     51 |     13 |    159 |
|     2 |   102 |     22 |     55 |    152 |
|     3 |   103 |     14 |     41 |    231 |
+-------+-------+--------+--------+--------+
```

But instead I want something like this, where the missing values of col0 are defaulted to 0.

```
+-------+-------+--------+--------+--------+
| UID   | IID   | COL0   | COL1   | COL2   |
+-------+-------+--------+--------+--------+
|     1 |   101 |     23 |     22 |    241 |
|     1 |   101 |     51 |     13 |    159 |
|     1 |   102 |      0 |     15 |    142 |
|     2 |   102 |     22 |     55 |    152 |
|     2 |   103 |      0 |     45 |     92 |
|     3 |   103 |     14 |     41 |    231 |
+-------+-------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Can anyone suggest a fix to my query or perhaps propose a better one? I'm running this on H2, so I reckon the query should be somewhat standard. Thanks:)

Comment: Add the feedback columns to the select and see if they are filtering.

Comment: @PreetSangha, thanks. Is this what you meant? https://gist.github.com/monsendag/f32957897950aa5bfb22

The query adds three feedback columns where the first contain zeros, the second ones and so on. What am I supposed to look for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `where` condition will filter out all the `null` (missing) entries. To avoid that, you need to move the `feedback = x` to the join condition. Try the following instead:

```
SELECT
yow.userid AS uid, 
yow.itemid AS iid,
isNull(col0.value, 0) AS col0,
IsNull(col1.value, 0) AS col1,
IsNull(col2.value, 0) AS col2
FROM yow 
LEFT JOIN yow AS col0 ON col0.feedback = 0 
AND col0.userid=yow.userid AND col0.itemid=yow.itemid
LEFT JOIN yow AS col1 ON col1.feedback = 1 
AND col1.userid=yow.userid AND col1.itemid=yow.itemid
LEFT JOIN yow AS col2 ON col2.feedback = 2 
AND col2.userid=yow.userid AND col2.itemid=yow.itemid
GROUP BY uid, iid
```

---

Comment: You had a typo after `ON .. `, but the assumption was correct, so it works as intended now. Thanks:)